# Move item from child to parent controller with draggable+droppable directive

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, draggable and droppable.  The directives themselves apply the jquery ui functions to the elements.  My draggable items are in a controller that has a parent controller with a droppable div.  How can I remove the item from the child controller item list to the parent controllers list.  Also removing the item from the list of draggables on screen and incrementing the droppable div length.

I have setup a jsfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/huNpS/1/

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        <div id="dropzone" data-index="1" droppable>
            {{dropped_items.length}}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items"
                data-index="{{$index}}" class="note" draggable>
                    {{item.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('parentCtrl', function ($scope){
    var dropped = [
            {id:1, title:'Note 1'},
            {id:2, title:'Note 2'},
            {id:3, title:'Note 3'}
        ];
    $scope.dropped_items = dropped;

});

app.controller('childCtrl', function ($scope){
    var data = [
            {id:4, title:'Note 4'},
            {id:5, title:'Note 5'},
            {id:6, title:'Note 6'},
            {id:7, title:'Note 7'},
            {id:8, title:'Note 8'}
        ];

    $scope.items = data;

});

app.directive('draggable', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.draggable({
                revert:true
            });
        }
    };
});


app.directive('droppable', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.droppable({
                drop:function(event,ui) {
                    var dragIndex = angular.element(ui.draggable).data('index');
                    var dropIndex = angular.element(this).data('index');
                    console.log(dragIndex);
                    console.log(dropIndex);

                    console.log(scope);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work. The quickest fix for this is simply not to use a child controller. Then you should have access to the same scope. Do you really need it?

If you do, you could set up events for this and use $.emit or $.broadcast on the $rootScope then set up a listener on the childCtrl that'll remove it from the list once dropped.

EDIT:

Now that jsfiddle is working, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/huNpS/2/

I removed the childCtrl and made the code do what I think you want it to:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('parentCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dropped_items = [
        {id: 1, title: 'Note 1'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Note 2'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Note 3'}
    ];

    $scope.items = [
        {id: 4, title: 'Note 4'},
        {id: 5, title: 'Note 5'},
        {id: 6, title: 'Note 6'},
        {id: 7, title: 'Note 7'},
        {id: 8, title: 'Note 8'}
    ];


});

app.directive('draggable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.draggable({
                revert: true
            });
        }
    };
});


app.directive('droppable', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var draggedElement = angular.element(ui.draggable);
                    var dragIndex = draggedElement.data('index');
                    var dropIndex = angular.element(this).data('index');

                    scope.items.splice(dragIndex, 1);
                    scope.dropped_items.push(draggedElement.data('obj'));

                    console.log(dragIndex);
                    console.log(dropIndex);

                    console.log(scope);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```